# Campo NULL em data, passando como parâmetro para o banco

Tags: c#, webforms

Estou querendo tratar um campo em meu programa para aceitar dados `NULL` caso não for preenchido, o dito campo seria `CliDtNasc`.
Fiz o tratamento na classe com o `if` ternário e nas propriedades da classe tratei para verificar se caso o campo é `NULL` ou não, vejam:

Classe:

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CliDtNasc) ? new
SqlParameter("@CliDtNasc",DateTime.Parse(CliDtNasc)) : new 
SqlParameter("@CliDtNasc",DBNull.Value))`
```

Code behind:

```
if (txtDtNasc.Text.Length > 0)
{

    objCli.CliDtNasc = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(txtDtNasc.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

}
```

Homologação:

Pesquisei o cliente XPTO que tinha a data de nascimento como "11/03/1994".
Apaguei a data e salvei. Debugando verifiquei que ele não trás como `NULL` no campo e, mantém a data. Porém, quando eu apenas modifico a data de nascimento o método que altera funciona.

[image: Erro]

Comment: Eu já tratei o erro de cadeia de caracteres. Porém agora ele está processando, mas não está permitindo a alteração. Sem erros.

Comment: Você quer replicar o `NULL` corretamente para o banco de dados, certo? Qual o SQL que está executando?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez  Correto. Estou utilizando SQL Server 2014

Comment: Ok, e qual o SQL? Preciso tirar uma dúvida.

Comment: Se você fizer um insert direto no bd funciona? Você está usando stored procedures pra fazer a `inserção/alteração`?